# Azure Cloud Service Losing Session if URL doesn't contain WWW

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles

My Azure cloud service app has users logged in with session data.  If they click on a link internally that doesn't have a preceding www, then the session data is not applied.  If they go back and click on a link that does have a preceding www, the session data works as expected.  Does anyone know how to resolve this?

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I share a session across multiple subdomains in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273732/how-can-i-share-a-session-across-multiple-subdomains-in-asp-net)

Comment: what have you tried and what didn't work? Are you sure the described scenario works well on-premises or shared hosting. My primary guess is that your issue has nothing to do with Windows Azure as a platform, but rather how you configure session cookies.

Comment: Other duplicate possibilities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474789/share-session-state-across-multiple-domains-in-net-not-sub-domains http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022382/shared-session-state-over-subdomain and several more.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.  The existing question you submitted as the possible answer is not correct.  The 2nd one you posted is more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your session cookies are not tuned to the wildcard of the domain.  Can this be a problem?  Check the forms section of your web.config if it contains domain attribute and if it doesn't, set it.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Account/LogOn" timeout="43200" domain="yourdomain.com"/>
</authentication>
```